# Проблема в позиционировании

Tags: html, css

```css
.price{
    position: absolute;
    color: #7db122;
    font-size: 15pt;
}
/*New icon*/
.special{
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    right: -1px;
    text-indent: -9999px;

}

.special .bue{
   background: url(img/NEW%20icon.png) no-repeat 55px -35px; 
}
```

```html
<li>
    <img src="img/prod2.png" alt="">
    <div class="products">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>
        <p></p>
        <div class="price-block">
            <p class="price">$90.00</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="special">
    <li class="bue">yjasfasfsafasf</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Проблема в чём, я хочу сделать что бы над товаром была надпись в виде картинки.

Вот в таком виде хочу что бы получилась:

[image: Вот в таком виде]

а получается в таком обрезанном непонятном виде:

[image: Вот]

Comment: z-index пробовали установить?

Comment: @Oleksandr Попробовал только что не сработало((

Answer (score 1):

Установите для картинки 
position: absolute и z-index чтобы она была поверх товара

Comment: проблема ещё в том что когда я ставлю position: absolute этот элемент у меня исчезает

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0c7qcqgh/  вы этого добиться хотите как я понял?

Answer (score 0):

```
.special .bue {
    background: url(img/NEW%20icon.png) no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    font-size: 255px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

попробуй так

поставь в top, right, width и font-size цифры на свое усмотрение, при position: absolute твой блок пропадал по нескольким причинам: ширина становилась равна нулю, слишком маленький шрифт и бекграунд картинка была смещена.

Еще, у меня нет информации что и как именно должно у тебя выглядеть, поэтому попробуй из .special убрать relative и поставить его в общую обертку. (надеюсь ты знаешь почему?) Чтобы твоя картинка двигалась относительно общей обертки, а не ul с высотой 0, как это у тебя в примере.

и мой совет - для таких задач лучше используй псевдоэлементы :before или :after, без всяких ужасных костылей с text-intend